# Get only objects inside "folder" in Google Cloud Storage C#

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a small sample code that is supposed to return only objects inside "folder" in Google Cloud Storage:

```
            var storage = StorageClient.Create();
            var listObjectOptions = new ListObjectsOptions(){ Delimiter = ""};
            try
            {
                foreach (var storageObject in storage.ListObjects(bucketName, "firstSubFolder/secondSubFolder/", listObjectOptions))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(storageObject.Name);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //
            }
```

What this code does, it returns not only objects inside secondSubFolder but it also returns the folder itself :"firstSubFolder/secondSubFolder/". I have tried many combinations using delimiter and prefixes, but can't really get it to return only objects from folder. Am I missing something or is this the way how it normally works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

There are 2 workarounds:

1. List the objects in a for with an index instead of a foreach and start from i=1 as the folder will always be the first object listed
2. Check if `storageObject.Name` is equal to `firstSubFolder/secondSubFolder/` and discard it from the output.

So it turns out that you can't use wildcards from a Client library, but only with `gsutil`.

---

**Original Answer:**

Try this `"firstSubFolder/secondSubFolder/?*"`

The '?' wildcard character means "match exactly one character" and '*' matches everything after it.

I tried it with `gsutil` not with C# but it should work.

See [Wildcard Names](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames#other-wildcard-characters) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I just tried it with gsutil and it works excellent! But unfortunately it does not work in C#. Do you have any ideas, what could be the problem?

Comment: It might be that the C# client library doesn't accept wildcard characters then :/ I can think of 2 workarounds. One is to do a for with an index and start from i=1 instead of i=0 as the folder will be the first object listed. Another one is to check with `storageObject.Name` is equal to `firstSubFolder/secondSubFolder/` and discard it from the output.

Comment: I have contacted google technical support and they say that:"Storage API does not support wildcards in a code unlike gcloud command line." They have provided the same workarounds as you, so if you could update your answer I would accept it.